# Android Emulator installation

Tags: android

Well I will be starting to develop android apps. I am very new to this platform. I have installed android studio and SDK. I now need to install "Google API Intel x86 system image". This is because i checked the "virtual device(1 GB)" option during android studio's installation wizard.  is this the emulator? can i develop apps without this API? or what is it?? It is a large file and i do not have much fast internet connection. Is it necessary to download and install these ?can anyone explain me?should i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an emulator image, for a particular version of the Android API.  For the Intel x86 images, you also need the Intel HAX emulation option installed.  Though, if you have your own device, testing on a device is a lot more convenient.  The emulators, even the faster x86 versions, are quite slow, and a bit unstable.  There is no reason to download this, unless you wish to test on an API version that you don't have a device for.

Comment: the AVD manager still allows me to create virtual devices without the image. Is it possible?

Comment: You may have downloaded an ARM image, otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

As ChrisCM said, this is an emulator image.

Plus, if you don't have your own device to test, I recommend to use Genymotion - https://www.genymotion.com/